# Does bluemix support any node engine?

Tags: ibm-cloud

How can I create a node runtime on Bluemix?

I am looking for something like this [Node.js on ChakraCore](https://github.com/nodejs/node-chakracore)

Without the help of default node.js buildpack, is it possible to execute node code

Answer (score 0):

Bluemix supports Node.js out of the box. For example, once you're logged in, you can navigate to the dashboard and then

- Click *Create an App* (in the ~Cloud Foundry Apps~) tile. Then click ~WEB~.
- Click ~SDK for Node.js~ (second from the left at the moment). Click ~CONTINUE~.

If you want to use a Node.js runtime other than default, you can use a community buildpack. Some community buildpacks (including a Node.js one) are also built-in to Bluemix, so you can select them by doing

```
cf push app_name -b nodejs_buildpack -p app_path
```

To use a completely external buildpack, you can specify its URL in the push command

```
cf push app_name -p app_path -b https://<url-of-buildpack> -s cflinuxfs2
```